# Drawing power from only one phase of a 3 phase alternator

Tags: three-phase, damage, alternator

*Note: I am busy learning about 3 phase alternators. A lot of my understanding is theory so I'm running through scenario's for better understanding.*

**Scenario:**

Lets say we have a 2 kW - 220 V - 50 Hz, 3 phase alternator with 3 live wires and no ground. The voltage between phases are 220 V.

We decide that we want to power a 180 W induction bench motor and 3 x 100 W light bulbs (480 W load) from one of the phases of the alternator.

We know that the 2 kW alternator is 80% efficient, so we should be able to safely draw 1600 watts from the combined phases and 533 W maximum per phase.

My questions are:

1. Are 3 phase alternators tolerant of drawing power from only one phase?
2. Will drawing from one phase cause the alternator to vibrate more?
3. Could drawing from one phase cause the alternator to wear out faster?

Comment: There is no generic answer. Read the data about the generator and don't make assumptions that what may apply to one device will apply to another.

Comment: If you only have three "Hot" wires and no neutral, you can't draw power from one phase - you must draw power between two phases.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can draw from one phase only
2. I don4t think som It never happened to me
3. It shouldn't be the case if you respect the criteria you mentionned